# Insertion sort not working Java

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

I have code to perform an insertion sort (ascending or descending, depending on the parameter) based on the title of a class called `Movie2`. Below is the code for the `main` method and the `sortTitles` method where the `printMovies` method prints the elements of the array.

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    Movie2[] myMovies = {new Movie2 ("The Muppets Take Manhattan",2001,"Columbia Tristar"),new Movie2 ("Mulan Special Edition",2004,"Disney"),new Movie2 ("Shrek 2",2004,"Dreamworks"),new Movie2 ("The Incredibles",2004,"Pixar"),new Movie2("Nanny McPhee",2006,"Universal"),new Movie2 ("The Curse of the Were Rabbit",2006,"Aardman"),new Movie2 ("Ice Age",2002,"20th Century Fox"), new Movie2 ("Lilo & Stitch",2002,"Disney"), new Movie2("Robots",2005,"20th Century Fox"), new Movie2("Monters Inc.", 2001, "Pixar")};

    System.out.println("Before Sorting:"); 
    printMovies(myMovies);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Sorted by Title - ascending: ");
    myMovies = sortTitles(myMovies,1);
    printMovies(myMovies);

} 
public static Movie2[] sortTitles (Movie2[] movies, int asc)
{
    if (asc == 2)
    {asc = 0;}

    for (int index = 1; index < movies.length; index+=1)
    {
        int other = index - 1;
        Movie2 movie = movies[index];
        int first = (int) movies[index].getTitle().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
        int second = (int) movies[other].getTitle().toLowerCase().charAt(0);

        for (other = index - 1; other >= 0 && (((first < second) ? 1 : 0) == asc); other-=1)
        {
            movies[other+1] = movies[other];
        }
        movies[other+1] = movie;

    }

    return movies;
}
```

My expected output is 
[image: Before and after sorting]

However, the output I receive looks like

```
Before Sorting:
The Muppets Take Manhattan, 2001, Columbia Tristar   
Mulan Special Edition, 2004, Disney
Shrek 2, 2004, Dreamworks
The Incredibles, 2004, Pixar
Nanny McPhee, 2006, Universal 
The Curse of the Were Rabbit, 2006, Aardman
Ice Age, 2002, 20th Century Fox
Lilo & Stitch, 2002, Disney
Robots, 2005, 20th Century Fox
Monsters Inc., 2001, Pixar

Sorted by Title - ascending: 
Monsters Inc., 2001, Pixar
Robots, 2005, 20th Century Fox
Lilo & Stitch, 2002, Disney
Ice Age, 2002, 20th Century Fox
Nanny McPhee, 2006, Universal
Shrek 2, 2004, Dreamworks
Mulan Special Edition, 2004, Disney
The Muppets Take Manhattan, 2001, Columbia Tristar
The Incredibles, 2004, Pixar
The Curse of the Were Rabbit, 2006, Aardman
```

Although some of the movies are sorted by title, others are not. No errors occur when I compile and the run the program and I am stuck as to what the problem could be with my logic. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Adding Movie2 Class code.

```
public class Movie2
{
// instance variables - replace the example below with your own
private String title, studio;
private int year;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Movie2
 */
public Movie2(String title, int year, String studio)
{
    // initialise instance variables
    this.title = title;
    this.year = year;
    this.studio = studio;
}

public String toString()
{
    return this.title + ", " + this.year + ", " + this.studio;
}

public String getTitle()
{
    return this.title;
}

public void setTitle(String titleSet)
{
    this.title = titleSet;
}

public String getStudio()
{
    return this.studio;
}

public void setStudio(String studioSet)
{
    this.studio = studioSet;
}

public int getYear()
{return this.year;}

public void setYear (int yearS)
{this.year = yearS;}
}
```

Comment: throw away the code and write proper object oriented code with a Comparator

Comment: Why did you use `.charAt(0);` and compare the first symbols of the titles?

Comment: @statut My assignment is to sort the array by the first letter of the title. I am comparing the titles to see which element in the array should go before the other.

Comment: You compare a movie with the previous movie, then move the movie **to the beginning**(?) if the movie is less than previous movie. You need to update value of `second` inside the loop, too.

Comment: @Andreas when do I move the movie to the beginning? Thanks for the `second` tip, that helped a little but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner for loop could be rewritten like this instead:

```
 while (other >= 0 && (((first > second) ? 1 : 0) == asc)) {
     movies[other+1] = movies[other];
     other = other - 1;
     if (other >= 0) {
         second = (int) movies[other].getTitle().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
     }
 }
```

The problem is the value of the variable `second` was never updated to point to the first letter of the title of the element that is being checked.

Here is the complete code for sortTitles with only the inner for changed:

```
public static Movie2[] sortTitles(Movie2[] movies, int asc) {
    if (asc == 2) {
        asc = 0;
    }

    for (int index = 1; index < movies.length; index += 1) {
        int other = index - 1;
        Movie2 movie = movies[index];
        int first = (int) movies[index].getTitle().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
        int second = (int) movies[other].getTitle().toLowerCase().charAt(0);

        while (other >= 0 && (((first > second) ? 1 : 0) == asc)) {
            movies[other + 1] = movies[other];
            other = other - 1;
            if (other >= 0) {
                second = (int) movies[other].getTitle().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
            }
        }
        movies[other + 1] = movie;
    }

    return movies;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works when asc = 1! However, it throws an ArrayOutOfBoundsException when asc = 2, not sure why.

Comment: It throws an exception because other is equal to -1 on the line `second = (int) movies[other]...` do you know why this could be happening?

Comment: Yes It happens in the case when `other` is equal to 0 inside the while loop, which causes the -1 problem. I edited my answer and added an if check that should prevent this from happening.